# Python 3.x - Cannot fix error: "slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method" + more

Tags: python, list, class, syntax

I'm working on a class that replicates the Sieve of Eratosthenes and have been getting the error message given in the title. Below is my code, more questions follow.

```
    class Sieve:

def __init__(self, max):
    if max < 0:
        raise RuntimeError
    else:
        self.numbers = [([False] * 2) + ([True] * (max - 1))]

def findPrimes(self):
    for i in self.numbers:
        if self.numbers:
            for j in self.numbers[i:]:
                if j % i == 0:
                    self.numbers[j] = False
                else:
                    None
        else:
            None

def howMany(self):            ##Must use reduce
    reduce((lambda i: True if numbers else False), self.numbers, self.numbers[2:])

def toList(self):
    T = [L[i] for i in self.numbers]
    return print(self.numbers)
```

So in the function findPrimes(self), specifically on line 14, I get the error message described in the title. What exactly is the source of the problem?

Additionally I want to ask a few questions about my methods. In findPrimes, I'm trying to visit each element of the list. If it is true, I want to take the index number (i) and visit all other indexes that are multiples of i (i, i+i, i+i+i, etc). I haven't tested this completely yet, but I feel like my syntax is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Finally, I need to use a reduce function in the method howMany in order to determine how many elements of the list are true, and return that number. Again, any knowledge on the topic is greatly appreciated.

Thank you everyone :)

Comment: I get `IndentationError: unexpected indent` when running your script.

Comment: Examine `self.numbers`. It isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to get at.

Comment: `(lambda i: True if numbers else False)` not sure this is what you want

Comment: @GregoryArnold: The outer set of brackets isn't doing what you were probably trying to do.

Comment: Looking at the code again, I see that there are quite a lot of problems. `howMany` doesn't return anything, those `else: None` blocks are pointless, and `return print(self.numbers)` is thoroughly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In python, `for i in self.numbers` works like Java enhanced For loop, where the For loop will iterate over the list, `i` will be the list entry (In your case, `True / False`) instead of the index.

If you want to access the list index, please utilize `for i in range(len(self.numbers))`, `i` will then loop from `0` to `(length of list - 1)`.